# Smoke Effect Colors Overly Dark and Gray When Rendering with Cycles or Eevee in Blender 2.92

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I tried to make a multi colored smoke effect because it looks cool. Unfortunately, this feature only seems to work with Workbench Render Engine while in wireframe view. Indeed, once I try to render with Cycles or Eevee, smoke is dark and gray. I tried to type "color" as some have recommended, but this doesn't seem to help. Here's the blend file in case you're asking: https://we.tl/t-DW0AlOQdOX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before *anything else*, here is an absolutely free YouTube video course on MantaFlow, which should give you everything you could *possibly need.* Here's the link: ( https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgO2ChD7acqElskP1q7SQKWgOybrO54Xv )

MantaFlow is still a bit finnicky, *especially* since recent updates changed its baking options. As such, you have to make certain you set up a few things before you begin your MantaFlow simulation.

**1**: It may sound silly, but: don't forget to add a light to your scene, before beginning your simulation.

Allow me to show you something you've probably shrugged off as a bug.

[image]

This is a picture of what a MantaFlow sim startup is *supposed* to look like.

[image]

and *this* is a picture of a MantaFlow sim startup when you forget to place a light in your scene (this is *all* in Solid Mode).

[image]

(delete everything, reset smoke sim without a light:)
[image]

Unfortunately, MantaFlow shaders in Solid Mode are *not* treated the same as Blender's built-in viewport mesh-shaders, which are automatically lit, *regardless* of the light from your scene. So you *need* to add a light source, otherwise your simulation will be dark, or rather, *unlit.*

Onto the next point, which I think will help fix your issue.

Let's take a look at *Principled Volume Shaders*. A *Principled Volume Shader* will allow you to easily color and light your volumes with a few simple clicks and swishes!

Your smoke domain comes with a *Principled Volume Shader* if you used *Quick Effects > Smoke*. You can access it from the shader tab by selecting the bounding box of your smoke domain.

[image]

Let's keep it simple, and answer the question above: *how can we turn this smoke blue?*

With your domain selected, you can change your volume's color using the "color" setting from your principled volume shader!

[image]

And we're done!

I hope that this helps! You're awesome, my friend -

And *keep the smoking to Blender!*
<3

Answer (score 1):

The color is there, you just needed some more light. :)

Also, the colors are multiplied by the color input of the *Principled Volume* node.

[image]